# Unable to put my TextView below the Toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-toolbar

i want to put my textview below my toolbar.now i know this has been answered but none worked for me.i am kind of new to android so just see once and tell me what change should i do? 
most of the time i found to add this line

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

my xml file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".activity.CancerActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCancer1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/Cause"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCancer2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtCancer1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/DetailCause"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Tooltip"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: did you manage to make it work?

Comment: yes @LeviAlbuquerque

Comment: could you share it with us? it could be helpful to someone else :)

Comment: it is in the answer. i wanted to know how to do it in relative layout.but anyway linear layout suits better for this kind of thing .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_below="@id/app_bar"
    android:id="@+id/txtCancer1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:text="@string/Cause"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

<TextView

    android:id="@+id/txtCancer2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtCancer1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:text="@string/DetailCause"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Tooltip"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
```

Comment: can u tell me what specifically you have changed? it works with relative layout also.

Comment: I set the  android:layout_below="@id/app_bar" to tell that the textview will be bellow the toolbar

Answer (score 0):

Use `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` (parent layout) and set `orientation` as `vertical`. You can also use `CoordinatorLayout` as parent. Also set the height of your `toolbar` as `?attr/actionBarSize`.

`layout_behavior` will work only if you use `CoordinatorLayout`.